# Error when export a csv list order

Tags: magento-1.9, error, importexport

I cannot **export order** list from **Magento backend**. When I am trying to do it, I am getting below **error**.

It would be appreciable if someone can help to resolve this problem.

[image: Problem image]

Comment: Hi Rebecca, warm welcome to the Magento Community. We are happy to have you. With the given details in your thread,  we cannot find what exactly went wrong in your case. First of all, the error message is not in English. Also you need to do some initial debugging and come up with more specific issue. In order to find the error, please put your site in developer mode and enable error logs. This will give you more details. Please use this link for more info: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Answer (score 0):

PHP likely ran out of some sort of resource. When I import or export out of Magento 1, I always adjust the values for the following PHP settings:

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
max_input_time
memory_limit
max_execution_time
session.gc_maxlifetime
```

This can be done using the php.ini file, or can usually be temporarily overridden in your *.htaccess* file in the root of your server.